# Convert column to datetime using pd.to_datetime with mixed YYYY and YY format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to convert my column to datetime but pandas is giving my the following error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Order Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' (match)
```

This is the function I am trying to run:

```
df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

This is a snapshot of the Order Date column:

```
Order Date
4/19/2019 8:46
```

Any ideas why this is not running? Thanks!

##### second question

I also would like to be able to convert mixed YYYY and YY for the year format (sometimes `'4/19/2019 8:46'` and sometimes `'4/19/19 8:46'`)

Comment: It seems that the word `'Order Date'` is actually _in_ the column. Error reproducible with -> `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['Order Date', '4/19/2019 8:46']), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your column, it looks like the string `'Order Date'` is in the column. The conversion on the example you provided works fine.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime('4/19/2019 8:46', format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Output: `Timestamp('2019-04-19 08:46:00')`

##### conversion of mixed YYYY and YY years:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['4/19/2019 8:46', '4/19/19 8:46']})
#              date
# 0  4/19/2019 8:46
# 1    4/19/19 8:46

pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace('^(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/)\d\d(\d\d)', r'\1\2',
                                      regex=True),
               format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

output:

```
0   2019-04-19 08:46:00
1   2019-04-19 08:46:00
```

Comment: The error that I am getting now is that is not able to find a match because some times the date is like '4/19/2019 8:46' and another time it is like '4/19/19 8:46'. Notice that the year changed. How could I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You could use a regex (and `str.replace`) to preprocess the column to remove the first two digits, then convert using `%y` (or add `20` to the year and keep `%Y`)

Comment: @zhivab check the updated answer (NB. I updated the question as this second question is *in fine* more interesting, and susceptible to help others, than the initial one)

Comment: By the way, in case it helps to anybody. I got this issue by combining different csv into one single dataframe. The csv had different formats in the column 'Order Date'.